# Call Interception Symbian C++ Series 60

Tags: symbian

On a Symbian S60 phone, is it possible to create an application that awakes when a voice call starts.I didn't want to dial a number through my application, i want that my application runs in background and as soon as the user dial a number for example "customer care", my application observe his dialed call and his call get dropped on one particular number and an application which is running in background came to foreground.
Plz let me know is it possible, if yes then plz tell how to work on that.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Monitoring_call_status_with_CTelephony) shows you how to monitor the status of a call from a Symbian executable. You then just need a background process to run to host this code - documentation for this you can find on Forum Nokia.